# What is the homotopy fiber of the map from a space to its James construction?

Tags: homotopy-theory

Given a pointed space X, let $J(X)$ denote its James construction. There is a natural inclusion $X\rightarrow J(X)$ which can equivalently be described as the unit map $\eta_X:X\rightarrow \Omega \Sigma X$.
The homotopy fiber of the counit map $\epsilon_X:\Sigma \Omega X\rightarrow X$ is known to be $\Omega X * \Omega X$. Is there an analogous result for the homotopy fiber of $\eta_X$ in terms of $X$?

Comment: I have the feeling that an analogous result would involve the homotopy cofiber of $\eta$, not the homotopy fiber. By the way, is $\ast$ the wedge product?

Comment: * is the join, ie the suspension of the smash product.

Comment: I believe for $X=S^{n}$ then one can get some answers p-locally by looping the EHP sequence. In general I am not sure what can be said.

Comment: There is not even a known identification of the homotopy cofiber $C$
of $e_X$ in general. There are some partial results: its suspension $\Sigma C$ is weak equivalent to  $\Sigma (X\wedge \Omega \Sigma X)$.
In the metastable range (approximately 3 times the connectivity of $X$), the cofiber coincides with the "co-join," i.e., the holim of the diagram $\Sigma X \to \Sigma X \vee \Sigma X \leftarrow \Sigma$ given by the two inclusions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It seems there is not a known answer for this question, as John implicitly claimed above. 

Answer (score 2):

This might not be a satisfactory answer, but let me point out that S.-c. Wong constructed a "little cube" model for the homotopy fiber of $\Omega^{k-1}E^n : \Omega^{k-1}\Sigma^{k}X \to \Omega^{k-1+n}\Sigma^{k+n} X$ in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02571721) in 1994.

Note that May's little cube model for $\Omega\Sigma X$ is essentially the James construction.